# Rails jbuilder what url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I'm starting to use `gem jbuilder` in a Rails 4 app.

If I create a view file called `show.json.jbuilder` in the `sites` folder, and the following url displays the json = `localhost/sites.json`

If I add a file called `tree.json.builder` to the same `sites` folder, what `url` can I use to display the json?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you decide what url to map to it based on your config/routes file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll want to make sure you have the route and controller action defined for `tree.json.builder`. For example, your route could be `localhost/sites/:site_id/tree.json` which could point to `sites#tree` (`sites_controller`, `tree` action) and display the relevant info in the `jbuilder` view. There is a number of ways you can go about this. I suggest reading through the [Rails routes docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to get a better idea of what's possible.